# Can't upload app for distribution

Tags: ios, software-distribution

I want to upload my app to App store so I tried so many ways which I will state.

1. I tried uploading using Xcode. The app has been successfully validated. When I try to distribute it, it gets stuck at uploading. Note my app is really small in size, about 8 Mb. the internet connection is perfect, nothing wrong with it. I waited for it for a while and it never showed me the progress bar that it usually displays. I tried archiving, validating, and distributing multiple times and it always gets stuck there. I regenerated the certificates and profiles and tried the whole process again and it didn't work.
2. I tried Application Loader. Here it gets stuck at "authenticating with the iTunes store...". I read in some StackOverflow post that I should try changing the port number in a java file "net.properties" from 443 to 80 as maybe my networking is blocking it. It also didn't work. I checked whether I'm using a firewall and it's disabled.

Now I'm pulling my hair. This isn't the first time I've upload an app. This is the fourth app I've released and you should count the updates I had released before and I have never been through this. What could be the problem? Any remedy to this?

Comment: try getting logged in with iTunes store in another tab and then try uploading.

Comment: in browser login in itunes.

Comment: as @Virussmca said login in itunes in a browser then try.

Comment: guys i logged into itunes connect in safari didn't work.

Comment: OH WAIT! progress bar appeared! i guess it's working now! what's the relation between safari and xcode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can not upload the app from distribution,

follow the step

[image]

Regenerate "iOS distribution provision profile" for **app store distribution** and download to mac.

Install it by double clicking it.

Try again using application loader to upload the build.

Thanks